# Does the Labrador current affect North Atlantic climate?

Tags: oceanography, ocean-currents, climate-models, arctic, ocean-models

This summer has seen very low sea surface temperature anomalies in the North Atlantic.

Using animations of these over the last year I feel the runoff of freshwater from Hudson Bay, into the Labrador current, and in turn into the Gulf Stream component of the AMOC, has been a cause of the disruption of heat transfer to the North Atlantic Drift.

Would this be correct? Has the runoff into Hudson Bay increased since September last year compared to a 10 year average?

Comment: Related: http://www.nature.com/nclimate/journal/v5/n5/full/nclimate2554.html

Comment: Thanks Aabaakawad. I am specifically interested in the mechanics of how the Labrador currents interacts with the gulf stream, and if this relates to the 25% contribution of freshwater to the sub-polar arctic that is Hudson Bay runoff

Comment: For example, labrador current is very cold but this time of year I doubt this us Greenland melt, yet hudson bay is also anomalously cold

Comment: @casey full pdf of the Nature article: http://fido.nrk.no/4cf750c3e0b034153d6ea12a898156b4a030f739896889be4a11b4526a97a663/Nature-climate-change.pdf